# Decode HTML encoded text in Dart

Tags: dart, decoder

It seems that Dart does not provide a default mechanism (or at least I could not find it) to decode HTML escaped entities.

What I'd like to do is convert eg. `Q&amp;A` to `Q&A`. (This is just an example)

As of version 1.11.1, Dart converts encodes these [like so](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/da0363172adaa266ef2d44cf87e09b61a185e79d/sdk/lib/convert/html_escape.dart#L187-192).

From there it is rather simple to create a custom converter implementation but that would not cover all the use-cases. Such as: what if `&lt;` is expressed with the hex value of `&#x3C;`?

Anyone got some pretty solution?

Answer (score 36):

I just made a small but complete Dart library for that exact purpose: [html_unescape](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html_unescape).

It supports:

- Named Character References (`&nbsp;`)

  - 2099 of them
- Decimal Character References (`&#225;`)
- Hexadecimal Character References (`&#xE3;`)

### Sync use

```
import 'package:html_unescape/html_unescape.dart';

main() {
  var unescape = new HtmlUnescape();
  var text = unescape.convert("&lt;strong&#62;This &quot;escaped&quot; string");
  print(text);
}
```

### Async use

You can also use the converter to transform a stream. For example, the code
below will transform a POSIX `stdin` into an HTML-unencoded `stdout`.

```
await stdin
    .transform(new Utf8Decoder())
    .transform(new HtmlUnescape())
    .transform(new Utf8Encoder())
    .pipe(stdout);
```

[More info + docs on pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html_unescape).

Comment: Great library. Just what I required to display different language converted from Google translated tools.

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Just use the [HTML parser](https://pub.dev/packages/html) library:

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
main() {
  print(parseFragment('Q&amp;A').text); // Q&A
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think Dart/Flutter can do it for you by itself:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

//  In production use library — universal_html: ^1.1.18
//  and — import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

void main() {
  String badString =
      'This &quot; string &quot; will be<strong> printed normally. &lt; &apos; &gt; </strong> &#62;';
      print(_parseHtmlString(badString));
}

String _parseHtmlString(String htmlString) {
  var text = html.Element.span()..appendHtml(htmlString);
  return text.innerText;
}
```

// It prints: This " string " will be printed normally. < ' >  >

Comment: The linter says "Don't use web-only libraries outside Flutter web plugin packages.
Try finding a different library for your needs."

Answer (score 3):

1- Add Dependency Package to pubspec.yaml:

```
    dependencies:
    .....
    html_unescape: ^1.0.2
```

2- Run in terminal:

```
   flutter pub get
```

**Example** how to use:

```
import 'package:html_unescape/html_unescape.dart';

Text(HtmlUnescape().convert(title));
```

if you are going to use multiple times, follow this:

```
var unescape = HtmlUnescape();
var text = unescape.convert("&lt;strong&#62;This &quot;escaped&quot; string");
  print(text);
```

> This "escaped" string

Answer (score 3):

### If you want to Extract the HTML content to Text String then Follow this step:

1. Add this plugin to `pubspec.yaml` =>
   [HTML](https://pub.dev/packages/html)

2. Then in your code add this block =>

   `String htmlText = parse("String with HTML tags").body!.text`
3. Then assign this varible wherever you want

Comment: Nice single line dependency less approach!

Comment: Adding a full HTML parser just to unescape text seems overkill.